# Selecting current page with toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, html

Since I didn't find a more suitable way to make the current page active I figured I should toggle a class when the link has been clicked. However, I cannot troubleshoot what's wrong with the element selector:

HTML:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel="#iframe">Panel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="#iframe">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="#iframe">Else</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').change(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('colorify', this.clicked);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/992f0y99/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use click instead of change:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('colorify', this.clicked);
});
```

`change` can be used only for input elements such as textboxes, textareas and checkboxes.

Comment: what is `this.clicked`?

Comment: @charlietfl that will return the boolean value true or false. Refer to doc : .toggleClass( className, switch )

Comment: @charlietfl so, that will result false.

Comment: right, which makes the toggleClass fail for switch case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a change listener on an `li`.

From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements.